# Creation of a spatial lag term in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, stata, spatial

I've been struggling to find a way to create a spatial lag term of my dependent variable, weighted by the distance between capital cities of countries in my data. Although weights can be based upon different things, distance between capital cities is what I'm interested in (of course, first I need to find a way to create a spatial effect variable and then lag it).

The dependent variable (DV) is an ordinal measure ranging from 0 to 2.

Sample from my data (if it can be of any help):

```
country  year       DV                **spatial lag?**
USA      2000       NA                     
USA      2001       2                      
USA      2002       2                      
USA      2003       2                      
UK       2000       1                      
UK       2001       1                      
UK       2002       2                      
UK       2003       NA
```

I know  that Stata has a command called [spmon](http://www.lse.ac.uk/geographyAndEnvironment/whosWho/profiles/neumayer/spmon.aspx) that can easily generate a spatial effect variable in monadic data (individual units not dyads). Unfortunately, I don't have Stata – but I guess there are ways of doing this in R?

**UPDATE**

I have the coordinates now – dyadic distances in kilometer. See the sample below.

```
ida  numb   idb      kmdist
USA  20     CAN       731
USA  31     BHM       1623
USA  40     CUB       1813
USA  41     HAI       2286
USA  42     DOM       2358
USA  51     JAM       2315
USA  52     TRI       3494
USA  53     BAR       3330
```

Exatly how can I generate a spatial lag term from the dataset above (lets assume that my DV – Y – is in the dataset)

Comment: In matrix notation, a spatial lag is just `X*y` where big `X` is your spatial weights matrix, and little `y` is your variable of interest. You will need to decide how to deal with missing values though.

Comment: thanks for this @AndyW – very useful. Now I need to find out how to get the big X, i.e. distance between capital cities. I need to admit that I'm not really sure about the math behind it. I guess there is a function that calculates  it (the distance between capital cities for each state?) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Assuming you have spherical coordinates (i.e. lat & lon) see the `spDists` function in the *sp* package. If you have projected coordinates you can just use `dist()`. Then you would want to set the diagonal to be 0 and take the inverse value for a spatial weights matrix.

Comment: @AndyW I've the coordinates now – dyadic distances in kilometer (Gleditsch & Ward). Now I just need to multiply it with my DV, right?

Comment: If you have made your spatial weights matrix that has `n*n` dimensions then yes. Other notes - you may want to normalize by the row sums of the matrix - so the resultant variable will simply be the inverse distance weight. Also if you have repeated measures over time you probably want your spatial weights matrix to account for that (e.g. only calculate spatial lags within the same year).

Comment: @AndyW I have updated the question, it is n*n now as you see in the sample. I have repeated measures over time but the distance does not change over time, for most states, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103643/discussion-between-fkg-and-andy-w).

Answer (score 2):

1. Build a weight matrix.
2. Double check the diag is all zero.
3. Normalize ...
4. One feature $X_1$
5. The variance of `w %*% x` is smaller than `x`.

```r
library(data.table)
sp <- data.table(
  location = letters[1:3]
  ,lat = c(20,40,60)
  ,lon = c(50,70,90)
)
sp
#>    location lat lon
#> 1:        a  20  50
#> 2:        b  40  70
#> 3:        c  60  90

library(tidyverse)
w_raw <- 
  sp %>% 
  dist(.$lat,.$lon,method = "euclidean", upper=TRUE) %>% 
  as.matrix()
#> Warning in dist(., .$lat, .$lon, method = "euclidean", upper = TRUE): 强制
#> 改变过程中产生了NA
w_raw
#>          1        2        3
#> 1  0.00000 34.64102 69.28203
#> 2 34.64102  0.00000 34.64102
#> 3 69.28203 34.64102  0.00000

w <- w_raw * (1/rowSums(w_raw))
x <- c(5,10,5)
w %*% x
#>       [,1]
#> 1 6.666667
#> 2 5.000000
#> 3 6.666667
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>